# How to add Child Data Sets inside Data Sets in Eclipse Birt with XML DataSource?

Tags: birt

I want to generate a report which consists of Reports inside a Master Report.

Example:

```
<MainAttachments>
<Attachment>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
</Attachment>
<Attachment>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
</Attachment>
<Attachment>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
   <Invoice>
      <ID>...</ID>
      <Usage>...</Usage>
   </Invoice>
</Attachment>
</MainAttachments>
```

When I configure all the data under single DataSet, I will get only single row output.

Please Help How to configure DataSet to get all the Invoice report under each Attachment ?

Comment: ...look into CrossTabs or Drill Reports techniques for including varied records

Comment: Hi @aRise, CrossTabs or Drill Reports doesn't give solution to my problem. I want something like, child report inside Master report. Everything needs to be printed on single page.

Answer (score 0):

@Hemalatha

Master(Customer)-Sub(Orders) Reports

[[1]: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBSK5_7.5.2/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/birt-13-2.html](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBSK5_7.5.2/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/birt-13-2.html)

Iam confident you will get your queries answered in the documentation link shared above.